# How to hide TieredCompilation warning?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, java

I'm using Linux Mint and OpenJDK.  `java -version` shows this:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Whenever I run a Java-based app like `lein`, I get this warning:

```
OpenJDK Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.
```

It's irrelevant to my interests, so I'd rather not see it in the command output. How can I hide or disable it?

Comment: Hi, do you know where exactly the warning is occuring?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in Leiningen. Its default installation contains the following line in the bash script it installs (eg. `/usr/bin/lein`):

```
export LEIN_JVM_OPTS="${LEIN_JVM_OPTS-"-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1"}"
```

There are two options:

1. change `+` to `-`;
2. comment out the line entirely.

Option 2 will disable the warning more comprehensively. This is because for certain tasks the Leiningen executable (in `~/.lein/self-installs`) will try to enable it anyway even in presence of `-TieredCompilation`.

Comment: i have the same problem and changing + to - or commenting out doesn't help.